# Change variable cells in OpenSolver model

Tags: excel, vba, solver

I am trying to change the variable cells in OpenSolver with a click of a button. Like with vba to change the OpenSolver model's variable cells.

I tried to use the following:

```
Sub ChangeVariableCells()
    ' Clear the existing variable cells
    OpenSolver.Reset
    
    ' Set new variable cells range
    OpenSolver.Range("A1:A10").Variable = True
    
    ' Solve the model
    OpenSolver.Solve
End Sub
```

But I get the error:

> the macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be
> disabled.

Even though I have enabled macro and "ticked" OpenSolver from the macro settings

Comment: The code as posted does not compile or run. Please post the full code you are using so we can help you.

Comment: Welcome user23548931! Read [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn your first badge!

Comment: This link may help [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)